# how to append a TextField properly with MaterialDesign Lite?

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design, material-design-lite

I try to append a new `text with floating label` with jQuery, but my appended textfield are not animated.

How can I make it animated ?

Here is my jQuery Code:

```js
$('body').on('keypress', '.stepcity', function(e){
    let keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (keyCode == 9 || keyCode == 13)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        let id = $('stepcity').length + 1;
        $('#StepCities').append('<div class="mdl-grid mdl-cell--7-col"><div class="mdl-cell--2-col CreateGroupIcons"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i></div><div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell--10-col"><input class="mdl-textfield__input hightlyVisible stepcity" type="text" id="StepCity'+id+'"><label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="StepCity'+id+'">Step City</label></div></div>');
    }
});
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make changes to the DOM, the Material-Handlers (like the animations that you miss) won't apply to these changes.
You have to call `componentHandler.upgradeDom();` in your javascript, after you have appended the html. Then it should behave like expected.

Also this seems wrong: `let id = $('stepcity').length + 1;`
It probably should be a class or an id-selector.